# What causes a window to not appear in the taskbar until it's Alt-Tabbed to in Vista?

Tags: winforms, windows-vista, taskbar

When our app is started programatically (either through custom action in MSI installer or when starting a new instance) in Windows Vista (also happens in Windows 7 Beta) it won't appear in the taskbar and isn't focused.  Alt-tabbing to it will make it appear in the taskbar properly and stay there.

What causes this?  I've seen this in some other apps before as well, but not sure why.  Out app is .NET WinForms app.  Never see this happen in XP, only Vista and 7

Edit: Well, it seems like the only time this happens reproducibly is when it's run by the installer, I believe there's other times it occurs, but I might just be crazy. The launching code is a bit complex to post because we handle various command line launch parameters and it launches a signin form before actually launching the main app etc.

Has anyone had to deal with this scenario before and worked it out?

Comment: How are you kicking off the application?  A code sample would help.
Also, look into what your application is doing during the load process.

Comment: We have same issues with a Clickonce deployed Winforms application

Answer (score 3):

Try checking your main application form "Form Border" property.
If it's ToolWindow (Fixed or Sizable), try changing it to FixedDialog for example.
This solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for this is that your main application window doesn't have the window styles that let Windows know it's a main application window (rather than a tool window or a dialog box).  So Windows is having to guess based on how the app was started, etc.

Use Spy++ to complare the window styles (especially extended styles) if your window to that of some other window that doesn't have this problem.  Are you missing the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style?  Are any other styles/extended styles different from other top level windows?

Answer (score 1):

G.So's answer made me find the solution for my problem, wich was caused by the fact that i had my form sizable from launch, but set to borderless in the load void.

If anyone is interested in how i managed to keep the switch to borderless and have it pop up as it should in the taskbar without any dirty hacks.. here it is..

Make a new event from the form on the form's "Shown" event, and put your line of code for switching to borderless in here. Problem solved :)

```
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    and for the lazy ones ;) >>>>

    this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
```

Thanks again G.So for clearing up what could cause this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I stuggled with this issue as well, and found like a previous commenter said, you cannot have anything in the form's Load() event that changes that FormBorderStyle property. Move anything that changes it to the Shown() event.

Answer (score 0):

> Never see this happen in XP, only Vista and 7

Maybe it's a bug in Vista...?

What happens if you call SetForegroundWindow() (or equivalent in .Net)?

**Edit**

I did of course mean "BringWindowToTop()".

Or do both.

Comment: Bug in Vista or not, the end user doesn't care whose fault it is, it happens in our app (and some others that I can't remember) but not 90% of apps out there, so in the user's eyes it's our bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution is to use a hack like [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Windows/Forcing_a_Window_to_Show_in_the_TaskBar/article.asp).   That's really not what it's for.

Usually the decision of whether a window will be in the taskbar or not is based on the border styles it uses.  The article I linked to provides a bit more detail.  The article's comment about the window having an owner or not is quite possible highly relevant to your issue, since the window might somehow be getting a different owner when launched by the installer.

That article is in VB but it's all based around API calls so the info it provides is pretty language independent.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same problem and fixed it by setting the form property showintaskbar property to true.

Weird that all windows os's dont run apps in the same way!

Answer (score 0):

In our situation, this was tracked down to the form's text property being changed within the `Load` event.

After putting this inside a `BeginInvoke`, this odd behaviour no longer happened.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Example

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    // this needs to be inside a BeginInvoke otherwise it messes with the taskbar visibility
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.Text = "Something new";
        }));
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue, also in Windows 8. Sometimes the form was receiving correctly the focus, but say just ~30% of the time.

We tried different solutions, but actually the one that worked was the following:

```
private void OnFormShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Tell Windows that the Form is a main application window
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

    // Even if true, enforce the fact that we will the application on the taskbar
    this.ShowInTaskbar = true;

    // Put the window to the front and than back
    this.BringToFront();
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.TopMost = false;

    // 'Steal' the focus.
    this.Activate();
}
```

Moreover, we ensure also not to set the title of the form during the Load event.

Comment: thanks, this helped me, but i only need the this.Activate(); line.